# How to dynamically extend the CARD widget height size based on the text in the card?

Tags: android-layout, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

So if I put a lot of text in a widget card the text will exceed the card widget and I can t see anymore the rest of it.

Only if I manually the size of each card it will show all the text.

Is it possible to dynamically extend the CARD widget height size based on the text in the card?

For example, no matter how much text I put there the height of the card it will extend in order to show all the text in it.

The code:

```
    Widget _card(
      {Color primary = Colors.redAccent,
      String imgPath,
      String chipText1 = '',
      String chipText2 = '',
      Widget backWidget,
      Color chipColor = LightColor.orange,
      bool isPrimaryCard = false}) {
    return Container(          
        height: isPrimaryCard ? 500 : 500,
        width: isPrimaryCard ? width * .90 : width * .90,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: primary.withAlpha(200),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0, 5),
                  blurRadius:
                      10, 
                  color: LightColor.lightpurple.withAlpha(20))
            ]),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          child: Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                backWidget,
                Positioned(                      
                    top: 20,
                    left: 10,
                    child: CircleAvatar(                         
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imgPath),
                    )),
                Positioned(                      
                  top: 30,
                  left: 20,
                  child: _cardInfo(chipText1, chipText2,
                      LightColor.titleTextColor, chipColor,
                      isPrimaryCard: isPrimaryCard),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a `ConstrainedBox`. It allows you to set a minimum height, but can expand if needed :

```
Card(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minHeight: 100,
    ),
    child: Text("")
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I can t figure it out in my code. I just updated the Question with some code.

Comment: Wrap the top `Container` with a `ConstrainedBox`, and remove its `height` parameter. I think that should do it.

Comment: I did but the whole text will vanish and I have a blank card. If I remove minHeight nothing happens.